# Calling C++ functions inside .lib file from Python

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2017, raspberry-pi

I made some .lib file from windows that consists of some functions and windows header. Is it possible to call the functions inside the .lib file in Python language from Raspberry Pi 3? I heard about CTypes, Cython, SWIG, Boost, etc. but i still can't fully understand how those works. I need your help, thank you.

Comment: `.lib` files are static lib, python needs dynamic lib which suffix is `.pyd`. You need to recompile them or rewrite function interface.

Comment: @YangHG. pyd files are for Python extensions specifically written to be used from Python. General .so files are suitable to be called from Python+ctypes (if providing a C call interface, C++ functions with name-mangling and exception handling are hard to call).

Comment: @MichaelButscher You are right, but maybe `.dll` instead, because I think he works on Windows.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, i'm new in using libraries file. Is it possible to convert my .lib or .dll file to .a or .so then using Python+cytpes/cython/swig/boost? But inside my libraries included some windows headers.

Comment: You should explain further what you want. What OS runs on the Raspberry Pi? Do you want to run libraries written for Windows on the Pi?

Comment: @MichaelButscher the raspberry pi runs with Rasbian NOOB OS. Yes, i want to run C++ functions inside my .lib file made from Visual Studio with Raspberry Pi Python language. Is it possible?